# sending js array of objects to servlet using jquery ajax

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, json, servlets

here's how the array looks like:

```
A[0] = { time, data[lon, lat], type }
...
A[n]
```

I want to send A to a servlet using jquery ajax and be able to have the same object on the servlet so I can access values like A[0].data[0].lat

I am wondering what is the best approach, I'm not a programmer and I've been searching and trying for a few days!

Comment: Try something first.....

Comment: This is what JSON is for...

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using JSON:
On the server side, use one of the JSON libraries listed on http://www.json.org.

On the client-side (jQuery), you'd want something like this:

```
var myData = JSON.stringify(A);
$.post('myurl.html', myData, function(data) {
    //success function
});
```

You could also use $.get if that works for you